# Краткий или короткий

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

**Кратким** или **коротким**?

> чтобы сделать столкновение как можно более кратким

или

> чтобы сделать столкновение как можно более коротким

Как лучше звучит? Никак не могу решить, посоветуйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: С столкновением эти слова не звучат. Лучше "быстрым".

Comment: с**о** столкновением

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Да, но тут как-то хочется произнести со сдвоенной (протянутой) буквой С.

Comment: Странно, что вам так хочется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В отдельных случаях в языке прижились обе формы - и полногласная, и неполногласная, но за ними закрепилось разное значение: сторона (бок, поверхность, вид с какого-либо направления) – страна (государство, держава), порох (взрывчатое вещество) – прах (пыль, останки), хоронить (погребать, предавать земле) – хранить (беречь, держать в неприкосновенности) и др.

К этой группе относится и пара **короткий – краткий**, где полногласная форма **короткий означает «небольшого размера», а краткий – «недолго протекающий, сжатый, лаконичный».** А значит, правильно будет сказать:  *..., чтобы сделать столкновение как можно более кратким.* Однако **короткое столкновение** тоже можно сказать в смысле **небольшое.** Здесь как бы оба смысла присутствуют - и по времени, и по силе, качеству, поэтому в **бытовом** разговоре обе формы корректны, смотря что Вы имеете в виду.

Comment: Имеется в виде "недолгое по времени". Да, я понимаю, что обе формы корректны, вопрос в том, какая лучше звучит в литературном смысле. Я склоняюсь то к одной, то к другой, уже замучился выбирать.

Comment: Сейчас подумал решил проблему по известному принципу: _"Здесь или сдесь? Пишите: тут"_. :) Заменил на _"чтобы завершить столкновение как можно быстрее"_. Спасибо!